# When using pinvoke, what is the base path for a dll when only the dll name is provided?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm calling the following from c#:

```
[DllImport("u3dapi10.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint dapiCreateSession(out uint hSession);
```

Where is .NET looking for the u3dapi10.dll file? This was working previously but now I'm getting a DLLNotFoundException.

The u3dapi10.dll file is in the root directory of the project. I tried copying it to the bin/debug directory just to see what happens, but it couldn't find it there either.

Possible cause:
Could this be caused by the u3dapi10.dll not being 64-bit compatible? e.g. Is a DllNotFoundException thrown if you try to access a 32-bit dll from a 64-bit machine? Or would it throw a BadImageFormatException as suggested by [BadImageFormatException when loading 32 bit DLL, target is x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728560/badimageformatexception-when-loading-32-bit-dll-target-is-x86)

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411736/p-invoke-dynamic-dll-search-path

Comment: That question does answer the first part of my question, could it also be caused by the 32-bit/64-bit issue?

Comment: I just encountered the error caused by the wrong bitness in the DLL just a few days in a test I was running .... and, sadly, I cannot for the life of me remember which exception it caused.  I *think* it was some kind of "badimage" style exception, but I would not make any decisions on that poor recollection attempt.  I need a memory upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After locating the dlls, I had the 32/64-bit problem. In that case, it does throw a BadImageFormatException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [Specify the search path for DllImport in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864673/specify-the-search-path-for-dllimport-in-net)

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx