# How to select the path for DllImport at run-time when the name of the required DLL can change?

Tags: c#, dllimport, loadlibrary

I have asked this questions today, but it was falsely closed and I have no option to re-open it. Therefore, I have to ask it again.

I have a class that has a long list of definitions like these:

```
[DllImport(NativeLibraryName, EntryPoint = "FunctionName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void FunctionName();
```

The parameter "NativeLibraryName" is set by a compiler switch. However, I would like to set this parameter at run-time. My problem is that there are two different DLLs I need to consider: one is for 32-bit systems and one is for 64-bit systems and they are different in name. What I would like to achieve is to determine whether the application is run with 64- or 32-bit and use the proper DLL. I need to load the correct DLL or otherwise I run into BadImageFormatExceptions.

**Switching to Delegates**

I could use Reflection to generate a file that does the same as the file that is given using delegates [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime). Here, I could provide the path to the correct DLL at run-time.

**Renaming DLLs**

I could also rename the two DLLs and have them the same name, but put them in different directories. I could then select the folder I want to load the DLL from.

Both options would work fine, but the project I am working on is a fork of an existing project and I want to change as little as possible so that I can easily merge updates from the original project into mine.

I am glad for any of your ideas.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411736/p-invoke-dynamic-dll-search-path) was falsely suggested as solution to my problem and the original thread was closed after that. This thread talks about a similar problem, but it does not provide a solution that is applicable to my problem. In fact, presents actually one of the solutions I came up with myself, but I am looking for better ways to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify a \[DllImport\] path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836093/how-can-i-specify-a-dllimport-path-at-runtime)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way is to ensure that the DLLs have the same file name (e.g. `MyNativeLibrary.dll`) and store them in separate sub-folders, e.g.:

- `x86\MyNativeLibrary.dll` for the 32-bit DLL
- `x64\MyNativeLibrary.dll` for the 64-bit DLL

When declaring your P/Invoke methods, you use the name of the library without specifying a hard-coded path e.g.:

```
public static class MyUtilityClass
{
    [DllImport("MyNativeLibrary.dll")]
    public static extern int DoSomething(int x, int y);
}
```

Finally, at the start if your application use [`NativeLibrary.Load(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativelibrary.load?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_NativeLibrary_Load_System_String_) passing in the full path of the DLL you wish to load. This has to be done *before* attempting to call any function of your DLL.

```
// Pseudo-code. You might need to adapt to find the path where your DLLs are located

// Get the folder path where the current `App.exe` is located
var startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName);

// Assume the DLL is in a sub-folder of the folder where `App.exe` is located
var myLibraryFullPath = Environment.Is64BitProcess
    ? Path.Combine(startupPath, @"x64\MyNativeLibrary.dll")
    : Path.Combine(startupPath, @"x86\MyNativeLibrary.dll");

// Load the appropriate DLL into the current process
NativeLibrary.Load(myLibraryFullPath);
```

Once an unmanaged DLL is loaded into the process, any future P/Invokes decorated with `[DllImport("MyNativeLibrary.dll")]` will bind to the already-loaded DLL, so that's why it works.

Comment: This was the same base idea I mentioned in my thread with "Renaming DLLs". However, you also provided a nice clean implementation. I was experimenting with generating delegates, but your solution is way cleaner. All I have to do is rename a given DLL whenever the project I forked gets a new update with a new DLL.

Comment: @c-augusto-proiete Does this approach work also for multi-platform (Windows, WSL/Ubuntu) native libraries, instead of the x32, x64 native libraries from your example?